# Illustrator - Clipping Mask inside a Bubble font

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, clipping-mask

From looking at [this screenshot](https://prnt.sc/saxier), I would like to put the pattern inside the text but keep the thick black outline. It is a bubble writing font. I have created 2 layers. One for the text, one for the pattern

I know it's a clipping mask of sorts (at least I think it is) but I have only been able to achieve this: https://prnt.sc/saxhrd

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

Your type shapes are **compound shapes**, i.e. shapes with "holes" or "counters".

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to select **only** the inner paths and delete them. Then make the mask. Or simply delete the inner shapes from your second image.

[image]

You have to click the actual *path* for the inner shapes. For the "O" you'll need to delete 2 paths as show in the animation above.

Comment: I'm struggling to only select the inner paths. I have used the DST but can only seem to get the outline of the text, rather than the inside part. https://prnt.sc/saxspe

Comment: @IdleAppsInc It takes a bit of practice. You have to click the **path** on the inside and *only* the path.

Comment: Use Ctrl+U to have better control when selecting paths or anchor points.